# My C program isn't running all the way through and I wasn't having this issue before with the same code

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Tokenizer.h"
#include <string.h>

//all other functions included in project folder (only issue is here)
_Bool tokenizer(struct lexics *aLex, int *numLex, FILE *inf){
  int y = 0;
  int n = 0;
  char buffer[256];
  //reading text file and should generate lexemes and tokenize and added to struct (defined elsewhere as well)
  while(fgets(buffer, MY_CHAR_MAX, inf) != NULL){
    //making sure we aren't at the end of the file
    while(buffer[y]!= '\0'){
      if(buffer[y]=='('){
        aLex[n].token=LEFT_PARENTHESIS;
        strncat(aLex[n].lexeme, &buffer[y], 1);
        y++;
        n++;
      }
      else if(buffer[y]==')'){
        aLex[n].token=RIGHT_PARENTHESIS;
        strncat(aLex[n].lexeme, &buffer[y], 1);
        y++;
        n++;
      }
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comments added for context. The issue has to be a loop somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for posting some code, now we just have to work on having code that's complete enough for us to help you debug.  For example, you haven't shown us how `MY_CHAR_MAX` is defined.  If `MY_CHAR_MAX` is less than 256, there's a big problem at the `while(fgets(buffer, MY_CHAR_MAX, inf) != NULL)` step, and this could be the source of your problem.  (Or it could easily be something completely different.)

Comment: That line `strncat(aLex[n].lexeme, &buffer[y], 1);` is pretty darn suspicious, too.

Comment: You have two nested loops. In the inner loop you increment the `buffer` index `y` in every iteration, but you don't decrement it or reset it to 0 anywhere. As you did not specify what the function is supposed to do, I can only guess that you might want to reset the index to 0 when you have read a new line in the outer loop.  What exactly means "program isnt running all the way through"? What input do you use? What output / behavior do you expect and what do you actually get? All this information should be part of a [mre].

Comment: To @Bodo's point: it would be much better (clearer for the reader, and safer) to use a `for` loop: `for(y = 0; buffer[y]!= '\0'; )`.  And maybe with the `y++` in there, too.

Comment: If the character in `buffer[y]` is none of `'\0'`, `'(`, or `')'`, it will just keep looping infinitely, since `y` won't change in that case.  You probably want to add an `else` at the bottom that increments `y`.